# Javascript reusable images caching?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

Is it possible to avoid asking server for 304 header for reusable images via jQuery or clean javascript?

Thanks ;)

Comment: AFAIK no, you would need access to the server configuration for this.

Comment: What configuration? It's doable via response headers, like Expire? I haven't tried it via javascript, but without js it's working until second refresh(F5). Need to check :)

Comment: Why not just change the ‘If-Modified-Since’ header?

Comment: If it is working until the second refresh it is possible that this is a browser issue. It is very well possible that your browser doesn't respect the expire header when refreshing the second time. Because if you refresh twice, you probably want a real refresh without caching.

Comment: If-modified-since is doing request to server and is using disk to check generated hashes.

Comment: It's strange why it's possible, when getting scripts dynamically.

Comment: Could you elaborate? By avoiding, do you mean not using cached images at all? Then you can use URL-params (`image.png?time()`) which continuously change.

Comment: No i'm willing to take them from cache all the time, until i'll decide, that images i outdated

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP image caching is done between webserver and webbrowser. You won’t be able to influence it with JavaScript, as the expiration/modification headers are HTTP headers, which will be handled by the browser, and not passed to JavaScript.

Comment: I'm talking about dynamic loading via javascript.

Comment: Yes, even with dynamic loading the requests are done by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving the images as javascript objects, ie.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "/test.png";
```

You can inject this object in the DOM as many times as you want and it will only request the image once.

Comment: Ah, you want to prevent it all together? That's gonna be hard.